# MySQL and Solr consistency, on insert to either

Tags: mysql, database, search, solr

I have a MySQL table that all users can INSERT into. One of the fields in the table is the total number of solr documents that the row matches, call it `total results`.

In the REST api code, on insert, I use a solr client to find the total number of documents that the new row matches. I update the field, then I return the completed resource. Simple enough, although I would prefer to somehow trigger this update automatically via MySQL.

The bigger problem is, on inserting new documents into or deleting old documents from solr, I now have no better plan than to execute a shell script that has the same logic as the REST api code, and run the `total results` update on each row.

My options, as I see it, are these:

1.) Update all rows after a `data_import` to solr, one by one. This table has approximately 1.5M rows, so it takes a while.

2.) Forego the field in the database altogether, and get every single `total results` sum from solr each time the resources are retrieved. (This is a very bad idea in my case because a user retrieves 20k rows from this table on login with GET /api/resource as a list)

3.) Find a way to determine which specific MySQL table rows a new solr document will affect, and limit the update to those rows. This would basically involve reversing the search process.

Solutions 1 and 3 basically require that I write a script that manages the solr `data_import` and the update of the MySQL rows' `total results` field as a single process. I can do that, but am at the point where I could use some insight on how best to manage these problems.

So, how would you maintain consistency?

Comment: Look up how Alfresco deals with the problem, "eventual" and "transactional" consistency, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

[Luwak](https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak) was designed to solve this issue (i.e. have stored queries and trigger them when the documents that are indexed match). You'd update the count of hits when a document matches a stored query. When deleting a document, do the same, but decrement the actual count instead.

This is a however a specific Lucene based solution, so it won't plug *directly* into your existing infrastructure.

Another option is to do the same thing manually; i.e. for each stored search - *if the search is a simple boolean match these terms-type of search*, decompose the search into tokens through Solr's analysis feature for the field type, and then do the same with the document when indexed. Look up each query that matches any of the tokens generated by Solr (in a different store, either in Solr or a separate SQL table) and then update the counts. Depending on the size of your documents this can be hard, but not impossible, to implement.

Elasticsearch has this as a feature under percolation, but that might also run into issue when you're talking about 1.5M stored queries. For Solr you'd index the document into a memory only index, and then run all the queries against that to find the queries that match.